# Routing problem with cucumber

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd

I am working with rails 3 and cucumber, all is going well except for this little problem

```
Given I am on the "edit automobile" page
  No route matches {:controller=>"automobiles", :action=>"edit"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

Now the path is set in paths.rb as edit_automobile_path

and in the routes.rb I have automobiles as a resource, I scaffolded it

so please tell me what I am missing, clearly the route is defined and matches, because I ran rake routes and saw the route.

please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `features/support/paths.rb` file for a path like this that specifies a unique resource you need to pass your `edit_automobile_path` an id,

in your rake routes it will look like `automobiles/:id/edit`

so you need to have `edit_automobile_path(:id`)

In order to do this in cucumber assume you have something like

```
Given I have an automobile
And I am on the 'edit automobile' page
```

In your given step def declare a variable `@automobile = Automobile.create()`

And  then in your paths.rb file

```
when /edit automobile page/
  edit_automobile_path @automobile
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I am still learning, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, ok back to work

Comment: no prob. dont forget, if this model becomes a nested resource, you will have to specify :automobile_id or whatever because it wont know what id to look for, so you will have to change the call in paths.rb to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

In your feature file you can do something like this :

```
Given I have an automobile
Then I want to visit edit automobile page for "automobile1"
```

Then in your step definition file:

```
Then(/^I want to visit edit automobile page for "(.*?)"$/) do |auto|
 automobile = Automobile.find_by_name(auto)
 visit edit_automobile_path(automobile.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to edit a particular automobile, I guess you can use the following within paths.rb:

```
when /^the edit automobile for "automobile1"$/
  edit_automobile_path(Automobile.find_by_name(page_name.scan(/\"([^"]+)/)))
```

so it passes the `automobile1` as a parameter to `find_by_name()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as mentioned below in your feature file :

```
Given I have an automobile
Then I want to visit edit automobile page for "automob"
```

Then in your step definition file:

```
Then(/^I want to visit edit automobile page for "(.*?)"$/) do |auto|
 vehicle = Automobile.find_by_name(auto)
 visit edit_automobile_path(vehicle.id)
end
```